# Powershell import CSV with multiple delimiters

Tags: powershell

I've got a CSV  that has multiple delimiters and the following format:
groupname;user1,user2;user3
groupname;user1,user2;user3,users4

How can i add the users to the AD groups. All the group names in the CSV ends with an ";" seperator and the users users use the "," seperator.

Comment: Have you tried anything besides asking here?

Comment: To give you a hint, I would use Import-CSV with one delimiter (probably ; if the data you posted is two rows) then split the user list on the commas.

Answer (score 1):

That's a going to make a jagged array if you try to split it at the ; and then split the member list at the commas during the import. It will be difficult to get imported as .csv because you won't have a consistent number of elements in each record.

I'd do the import-csv using the ; as the delimiter, and then split the member list at the commas when it's time to add the members.

Answer (score 0):

Does the header and data still match up, even with different delimiters? If so, I'd replace the odd delimiter with a comma and then to the import. Unless the file is enormous, I'd simply make a clean, second copy and import that.

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
Import-Csv -Path $inputfile -Delimiter ';' |  export-csv $outfile -Delimiter ',' -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation 
Import-Csv -Path $outfile -Delimiter ','
```

First take in with `;` then export that with `,` and then take the whole bunch in as a `,` separtated file.